# Symfony test: очень долгое очищение БД в режиме truncate

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony 3.4, бд mysql.

Перед каждым тестом очищаю базу данных, чтобы залить только необходимыми значениями.  Использую truncate, чтобы сбросить счетчики инкрементации ID.

Перед каждым тестом запускаю следующий код:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$em->getConnection()->exec('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;');
$purger = new ORMPurger($em);
$purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE);
$purger->purge();
$em->getConnection()->exec('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;');
```

Однако данный участок выполнятся 10-20 секунд, что как то многовато для каждого теста.

Но если удалить `$purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE);` то очищение будет через delete и гораздо быстрее. Примерно 100мс.

Как уменьшить время выполнения скрипта, или какой другой способ чистки БД?

Comment: а вы пробовали в базу данных ничего не записывать, все тесты проводить в транзакциях и потом их отменять?

Comment: @Ghost Не пробовал. Но смысла не понял. Если я будут их отменять, то у меня и в базе ничего не будет. Как я например проверю запись в базу, или как потом что-то от туда вытащить, если транзакция не закоммичена?  
Сценарий простой: загрузить фикстуры в базу, забрать объект из базы - что то выполнить для теста.

Comment: накатить фикстуру, старт транзакции, тесты, проверки, откат транзакции, после всех тестов подчистить за собой

Comment: @Ghost В общем я не понимаю по следующим причинам:
1) Что мне дадут транзакции? Откатить можно только незакоммиченную транзакцию. Не закоммиченная транза - не видна в базе, я не смогу делать тесты по невидимым никем данным.  Толку мне от незакоммиченных данных? А закомиченные отролить нельзя. 
2) "Накатать фикстуру" - Чтобы накатить фикстуру мне сначала надо почстить тестовую базу, перед прошлым тестом - а в этом и есть проблема. Фикстуры для каждого теста разные, перед каждым тестом чистится база.

Comment: Что мне дадут транзакции? Откатить можно только незакоммиченную транзакцию. Не закоммиченная транза - не видна в базе, я не смогу делать тесты по невидимым никем данным. они вам не видны, а в рамках транзакции видны, значит фикстуру тоже в транзакцию помещать. вы же не вручную после тестов проверяете наличие данных? во всяком случае в моем проекте так работает и это позволило сильно сократить время прохождения тестов. мб в вашем случае не подходит

Comment: @Ghost кажется понял, спасибо. Попробую как вариант.  Весь тест проводить внутри транзакции, без предварительной чистки базы.  Как вы и написали в первом сообщении, не понял сразу.

Comment: Как вариант, если вам нужно сохранить ключи (id), вы же можете в фикстурах их задавать. Тогда можно пользоваться очисткой через delete.

Comment: @danil как вариант - возможно, спасибо. Только надо тогда во всем сущносятх ставить setId + могут возникнуть проблемы с дубликатами, если по какой то причине фикстура одного типа будт залита в тесте несколько раз.

Comment: @Ghost Попробовал транзакции. Да, все прям залетало. Но оказывается, что транзакции не откатывают AUTO_INCREMENT значения. А именно из-за них я и делаю truncate.